# My node js fetch function from a json file is not displaying json data on console

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch

I'm new to node js and currently bulding a web server to get a list och team members from a json file in the json folder, but my fetch function is not displaying the data on the console. I get a **TypeError: only absolute URLs are supported**. Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const app = express();

const host = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 3000

async function loadTeams() {
    return (await fetch("/prov-nodes.json")).json();
    
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let teams = [];
    loadTeams()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(function(data){   
        teams = data; 
        console.log(teams);  
            //res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      res.send("My root page");
      console.log(teams);  


});

app.get('/maths', (req, res) => {
    res.send("My maths page")
});


app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at: http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: `fetch("/prov-nodes.json")` is not an absolute url, it's an absolute path - the error states you need to use an absolute URL ... i.e. you need `http[s]://domain.com/prov-nodes.json` - where `domain.com` is the server you are requesting the data from

Comment: also, since loadTeams returns the `.json()` result ... `.then(response => response.json())` would fail

Comment: @JaromandaX, Thanks for your prompt reply. The json file "prov-nodes.js" is existing in a json folder, but i got the same error, that's why i had a copy on the same folder as the app.js. Must i still use "http[s]"?

Comment: yes ... because fetch in node only works with absolute URLS's - as the errors clearly states, and as I explained in the first comment

Comment: Why are you using fetch *at all* if it's a local folder?

Comment: @JaromandaX, i've tried using your way as follows and still failed.                      async function loadTeams() {
    return await fetch("https://127.0.0.1/prov-nodes.json").then(res=>res.json());
    
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let teams = [];
    loadTeams()
      .then(function(data){   
        teams = data; 
        console.log(teams);  
            //res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      res.send("My root page");
      console.log(teams);

});

Comment: well ... do you have a https server running on 127.0.0.1 that handles the request of `/prov-nodes.json`

Comment: if the file `prov-nodes.js` exists in a folder accessible by your code ... why `fetch` it? use `fs` methods to read it and send it!!!

Comment: @JaredSmith, my json file resides in a json folder within the project. What should i use if not fetch?

Comment: The file system?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the absolute path of your local file like D://somewhere/your_project//prov-nodes.json

```
await fetch("D://somewhere/your_project//prov-nodes.json")).json();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jaromanda and @Jared Smith asked why i'm using fetch if it's in a local folder? I recently used fetch when learning React, so i tried to use it the same way. Does it mean that Fetch should not be used on a local folder in Node js? So installing node-fetch only applies to fetching a http url?
I changed my code to use "fs" and it worked. But i could see the json data through the terminal but not on the "Dev tools" console in the browser.

Comment: You seem to be very confused about the difference between client-side and server-side. I recommend doing some googling about the difference.